# Unable to post photos on Wall using Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I am facing the following issue while using Android FaceBook SDK 3.0. When using:

```
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
```

It works fine when I use

```
String response = facebook.request(null, params, "POST");
```

but then it posts photos in Album named same as Application name. 
I want to post on the wall.
So when I use

```
String response = facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
```

It does not work and response contains error -

```
"error":{"message":"Unsupported method, photos.upload","type":"Exception"
```

How does the first parameter work and how can I post to the newsfeed?

Answer (score 0):

Add "caption" to your method. like

```
params.putString("caption", caption);
```

where caption is name of your album, when you provide this, it will create an album of specified name and put image inside.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the list of albums the user has (me/albums), then from that list find the album whichs type is "wall" and post your image to this album.